# How to store parseObject locally as well as in parse Cloud using parse sdk of android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I enable local datastore:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(mContext);
Parse.initialize(mContext, PARSE_APP_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
```

and now i try to save changes of current parseUser to local dataBase as well as Parse Cloud

```
mParseUser.put(DBConstants.KEY_TAKEPICEVERY, takePicEvery);

//Save in local database
mParseUser.pinInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
  @Override
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    //try to save in Parse Cloud
    if(e==null)
      mParseUser.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {        
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e1) {
          Log.e("Save Done:", "="+e1);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

`saveEventually` never saves the updated info to the Parse Cloud not even `saveInBackground` works.

Comment: Same here, filed an issue on github: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/287